# three20 right align

Tags: iphone, stylesheet, alignment, three20

is there a way to right align div tag inside a styled text item in three 20 on iphone?  I have accomplished it using the following:

```
return 

[TTBoxStyle styleWithMargin:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20, 230, 5, 5) padding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0) minSize:CGSizeMake(20, 20) position:TTPositionStatic next:nil];
```

however, this only works in portrait orientation, when i rotate the device into landscape, the div stays statically and does not stay rotated.  how can i either keep it right aligned, or get access to the window/view within the stylesheet class to be able to calculate it?

thx
Ben